# mysql server does not return full error message

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm trying to write a recursive function to delete records using mysql-python-client: each time the function call depends on the last returning `IntegrityError` message which can be used to create a new sql to be executed. At the beginning, the code ran smoothly, but it stops with an `AssertionError` which cause by the `err` is not a complete info like:

`` Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_name`.`a_table_name`, CONSTRAINT `FK_xxx` FOREIGN KEY (`foreign_key_name`) REFERENCES `incomplete_reference_table_name) ``.

**So, WHY is the error message incomplete and HOW to make it return a full complete message?**

Additional Info: I tried with `golang>"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"` and even navicat IDE the result is all the same. It seems it's a server side BUG?

**Update**:
test result with CLI:
[image]
test reulst with CLI in text:

```
mysql> delete from `bnb_system`.`traveler_checkin_handle_record` where `room_id` in (select `id` from `room` where `fk_roomtype_rooms` in (select `id` from `room_type` where `fk_inn_roomtype` in (select `id` from `inn` where landlord_id in (select id from landlord where user_id in (select id from user where tel='15779313733')))));
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bnb_system`.`concerned_checkin_traveler_check_in_handle_record`, CONSTRAINT `FKc2166ey4rteqht79ahel72scu` FOREIGN KEY (`traveler_check_in_handle_record_id`) REFERENCES `traveler_checkin_handl)
```

```py
import mysql.connector
import re

host = "some_host"
user = "some_user"
password = "some_pwd"
database = "some_system"

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=host,
                                     user=user,
                                     password=password,
                                     database=database)
cur = conn.cursor()
org_sql = "some_sql"


def recursive_delete(sql, cur, conn):
    sql_post = sql[sql.index('where'):]
    try:
        print(sql)
        cur.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
    except mysql.connector.IntegrityError as e:
        err = e.msg
        print(err)
        ss = r'`[\w_]+`'
        info = re.findall(ss, err)
        assert len(info) == 6, "error message: {}".format(err)
        db, table, foreign_key, reference_table, reference_key = info[0], info[1], info[3], info[4], info[5]
        new_sql = "delete from {db}.{table} where {foreign_key} in (select {reference_key} from {reference_table} {sql_post})".format(db=db, table=table, foreign_key=foreign_key, reference_key=reference_key, reference_table=reference_table, sql_post=sql_post)
        recursive_delete(sql=new_sql, cur=cur, conn=conn)


recursive_delete(sql=org_sql, cur=cur, conn=conn)
```

Comment: MySQL server always returns full error message. Connector always transfer server's answer unchanged. If you get it only partially then this is answer processing issue (on the python side).

Comment: @Akina no. I tried with golang even IDE navicat and result show no difference

Comment: Test the same using CLI. Error message must start with ERROR 1451 (23000). The message posted by you is the complete rest of the error message - its starting part may be removed diring error message parsing and stored in some another atrtribute of the error reporting object. Anycase it is NOT MySQL issue.

Comment: @Akina updated my post with CLI test result image/

Comment: Please post CLI error message in textual form, replace confidential names or name parts with "database_name", "column1_name", etc. And, as I see on the screenshot, MySQL returns normal, full, error message - so the beginning is removed during transferring by another software. As I have claimed, this is not MySQL issue. Or maybe you mean some another info when you tell that the message is partial?

Comment: @Akina update. Please recheck the image and text result in CLI. At the end of the error message, there's only `'traveler_checkin_handl `, and the complete result should be `'traveler_checkin_handle_record' ('id')`, the `'e_record' ('id')` is lost.

Comment: This is a norma - server must give you the information which is enough for the problem source detection. You can see problematic table name `bnb_system.concerned_checkin_traveler_check_in_handle_record` and the name of constraint `FKc2166ey4rteqht79ahel72scu` which fails. This is enough, if you need in more detailed information you may get it from problematic table's DDL. Removing excess code tail is a common and normal MySQL server practice. Theoretically full code citate may be extremely long, MySQL simply saves its own, network and client resources.

Comment: @Akina All right, that seems it's a mysql server implementation limitation. I changed get SQL splice inf from the return error message to query the information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.  That solved my problem. And many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I changed the implementation of how to query the reference tables in `information_schema`, that solved the problem.

```py
def recursive_delete(all_sql, cur, conn):
    for sql in all_sql[::-1]:
        sql_post = sql[sql.index('where'):]
        try:
            print(sql)
            cur.execute(sql)
            conn.commit()
        except mysql.connector.IntegrityError as e:
            err = e.msg
            ss = r'`([\w_]+)`'
            info = re.findall(ss, err)
            db, table, constraint_name, foreign_key = info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3]
            sql_reference_table_and_reference_key = 'select REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME="{table}" and CONSTRAINT_NAME="{constraint_name}" and COLUMN_NAME="{foreign_key}"'.format(table=table, constraint_name=constraint_name,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              foreign_key=foreign_key)
            print(sql_reference_table_and_reference_key)
            cur.execute(sql_reference_table_and_reference_key)
            result = cur.fetchone()
            reference_table, reference_key = result[0], result[1]
            new_sql = "delete from {db}.{table} where {foreign_key} in (select {reference_key} from {reference_table} {sql_post})".format(db=db, table=table, foreign_key=foreign_key, reference_key=reference_key, reference_table=reference_table, sql_post=sql_post)
            sql_strings.append(new_sql)
            recursive_delete(all_sql=all_sql, cur=cur, conn=conn)
```